# Error while updating to latest pm2

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2

I tried updating pm2 with "npm install pm2@latest -g" (Cent OS 6) but received the following error. Now, i am no longer able to use "pm2 list" (it says command not found). Your help will be highly appreciated.

npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-042stab094.8
npm ERR! argv "node" "/home/username/local/bin/npm" "install" "pm2" "-g"
npm ERR! node v0.12.1
npm ERR! npm v2.7.3

npm ERR! Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR! https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Latest npm (2.11.1) solved this issue. 
Thanks.